# Average Innings Score in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try the code for  this program in c++ , it successfully completed all the test cases. but in python language  it shows an value error for same logic.How to solve this ?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVLmv.jpg
My code :

```
def avg(s,n):
  sum1=0
  sum2=0
  for i in range(0,n):
      for j in range(0,2):
          if j%2==0:
             sum1+=s[i][j]
          else:
             sum2+=s[i][j]
  print((float)(sum1/n))
  print((float)(sum2/n))
n=int(input())
c=2
s=[[0 for j in range(0,c)]for i in range(0,n)]
for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(0,c):
        s[i][j]=int(input())
avg(s,n)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are taking input is wrong

When you do this `s[i][j]=int(input())` you are converting two space separated ints to a single int

```
def avg(s,n):
  sum1=0
  sum2=0
  for i in range(0,n):
      for j in range(0,2):
          if j%2==0:
             sum1+=s[i][j]
          else:
             sum2+=s[i][j]
  print((float)(sum1/n))
  print((float)(sum2/n))
n=int(input())
c=2
# I am going to ask for user input n times, split the input every time and convert individual score to int 
s=[list(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(n)]
avg(s,n)
```

```
2
100 200
200 300
150.0
250.0
```

Comment: Thank You..! But , It want to displays the output upto two decimal places..?

Comment: You can search that, based on the question, this is the solution

Answer (score 0):

To print the average innings up to two decimal places we can use this code

```py
print(" %.2f" % (sum1 / n))
print(" %.2f" % (sum2 / n))
```